# get post - wrong selection

Tags: mysql

This code didn't works as expected. I want to select all the posts that have the TAGS `561, 562`, together or separately, but without any tag that is not present here->>> `IN (561, 562)`

```
 SELECT post_id_post
 FROM post_has_tags
 WHERE tags_id_tags IN (561, 562)
 HAVING COUNT(tags_id_tags) <= 2 

post_id_post        tags_id_tags    
600                    561  
600                    562  
600                    917  // 917 is not inside IN (561, 562)
```

But this code will output the post 600. It's wrong, the correct output should be no results.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
select distinct p1.post_id_post from post_has_tags p1
where not exists (
  select * from post_has_tags p2
  where p1.post_id_post = p2.post_id_post and p2.tags_id_tags not in (561, 562)
)
```

I don't want to be less than Phil, so I'm adding my [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1c76/1) too :)

Comment: You get a +1 from me for having a more terse query. You don't need the `WHERE .. IN` on the outer query like I have in my answer

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT pht.post_id_post -- the distinct is to avoid duplicates
FROM post_has_tags pht
WHERE pht.tags_id_tags IN (561, 562)
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM post_has_tags _pht
    WHERE _pht.post_id_post = pht.post_id_post
    AND _pht.tags_id_tags NOT IN (561, 562)
);
```

Demo here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cdef3/3

Answer (score 0):

maybe a bit overkill but:

```
SELECT post_id_post
FROM post_has_tags
WHERE tags_id_tags IN (561, 562)
AND tags_id_tags NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(tag_id) FROM tags WHERE tag NOT IN (561, 562));
```

(assuming you have a separate table for tags)